# Get list of all rooms (Django channels 2)

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to get list of all created rooms in Django channels 2.x?
I have checked documentation and there is no method which returns list of created rooms.

Answer (score 2):

If this question is about listing all groups in django-channels 2:

If django-channels 2 is configured for using Redis as the backend it stores all groups in Redis under the keys prefixed with: "asgi::group:".

To list the groups the following code can be used:

```
r = redis.Redis.from_url(REDIS_URL_USED_BY_CHANNELS_2)
prefix = 'asgi::group:'
groups = [key.decode('utf-8')[len(prefix):] for key in r.scan_iter(prefix + '*')]
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a built in way for Channels to get a list of groups but you can achieve this by adding/removing group names to a model field with some logic in your consumer's `connect()` and `disconnect()` methods.

Answer (score 1):

In their [github project](https://github.com/ml-learning/django-channels-presence/blob/master/channels_presence/models.py), they don't overwritten the `all()` method, so all created rooms are accessible via:

```
Room.objects.all() # can filter
```

Whereas methods available via `RoomManager` are : `add()`, `remove()`, `prune_presences()`, `prune_rooms()`. See the [Official Documentation](https://django-channels-presence.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#room)

Comment: Channels 2 doesn't have a Group class and as such Channels_presence doesn't work.